# How to prevent animation of back button when switching views?

Tags: ios

I cannot figure out how to disable the back-button animation that occurs in the navigation bar when switching from a tableview to a standard view (when a cell is selected).  There is no obvious line of code that enabled animation to begin with.  Here it is in gif-form:

[image: demo]

The navigation buttons in the Facebook app do not animate, so it is possible.

It may be relevant to mention that I am using the [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) library to create the Facebook-like tableView menu, i.e. swipe to the right to expose a table.

EDIT: solution is based on Hesham Abd-Elmegid's answer but modified to use a custom image...

```
UIImage *settingsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button@2x.png"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 10.0, 29.0, 29.0);
[backButton setBackgroundImage:settingsImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a custom `UIBarButtonItem` as a left navigation item (instead of standard back button item), it will fade instead of slide in, just like in Facebook's app. Just create a simple method that will replace back button functionality by calling `popViewControllerAnimated:` on the navigation controller in which your detail view controller is contained.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack)] autorelease];
}

- (void)goBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note: `UIBarButtonItem` can also be set up with an image using `initWithImage:style:target:action:` method.

Comment: Thanks!  This did what I needed functionally, but when I added the custom back button it placed it inside of the default button.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what is the problem with custom back button? Or even better, submit a new question so we don't go too much offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the back button with a custom UIButton. That way it won't animate on transition.

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
[customBarItem release];
```

You will have to find a PNG for the arrow shape of the back button though.